# Lambda Expression that has return type as void can compile with wrapper but not compile with primitive

Tags: java, java-8, lambda

```
   interface A {
        void s();
   }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = () -> 5; // DOES NOT compile
        A b = () -> new Integer(5); // does compile
        A c = () -> Stream.of(1, 2, 3); // does compile
    }
```

What is the reason that the first line does not compile and the second and third one does ?

Comment: I guess it's because 5 is not a statement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Wrapper vs primitive is not the cause.  The following will not compile either:

```
Integer i = 5;
A b = () -> i;
```

This is covered in [JLS 15.27.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.27.3):

> If the function type's result is void, the lambda body is either a statement expression (§14.8) or a void-compatible block.

`5` is neither a statement not a void-compatible block.  So `A a = () -> 5;` will not compile.

The reason for this restriction is that void-returning lambda only makes sense if it operates by a side-effect.  Simply returning a value like `() -> 5` has no side effects and therefore such a lambda expression is definitely a bug.

Comment: Note: the single line `5;` (inside a method, not lambda) will also not compile

Answer (score -8):

when jvm compiles `A a = () -> 5;` it convert lambda expresssion as following

```
void s(){
  return 5; //
}
```

when jvm compiles `A b = () -> new Integer(5);` it convert lambda expresssion as following

```
 void s(){
       new Integer(5);
    }
```

> Hence, until you won't perform initialization, expression would
>   considered as return values.

Comment: the basic idea is correct, but compiler more likely *thinks* of `int s() { return 5;}` based on error message: "incompatible types: lambda body is not compatible with a void functional interface" (instead of "incompatible types: unexpected return value")